# Existence of a basis for a given transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $f:R^2 \rightarrow R^3$ defined as $f(x,y)=(x+y,x-y,3y)$ I'm asked to determine if there is a basis $B_1,B_2$ of $R^2$ and $R^3$ such that the transformation matrix of $f$ in these basis is

$M(f,B_1,B_2)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array} \right)$

If we consider the following two systems of linear equations:

$\begin{cases}x+y=1\\x-y=0\\2y=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}x+y=0\\x-y=1\\2y=0\end{cases}$

then $x=y=0$ in both cases. Is that enough to say that there are no basis that satisfies the conditions?

Comment: Is this the right matrix of the transformation?

Comment: Yes, copied directly from the exercise. Is the matrix of the transformation the same as the matrix associated to f in basis B1 B2?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb{R^2}$ you can have the standard basis $B_1=\left\{ (1,0),(0,1)\right\}$. To find $B_2$ we apply the given transformation to the elements of $B_1$ to get

$$ B_2=\left\{ (1,1,0),(1,-1,3)\right\} $$

which is equivalent to the basis

$$ B_2=\left\{ ( 1,0,0 ), ( 0,1,0 ) \right\}. $$